# Recursive string comparison

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am trying to compare two strings, to see if one string contains the other one and what point. So basically I am trying to find **indexOf**. However, I don't want use it.

This is the code I have written that works perfectly using indexOf:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Index
{
  public static void indexOf(String main, String check)
  {
    System.out.println(main.toLowerCase().indexOf(check.toLowerCase()));
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    indexOf("Barack Obama", "Obama");
  }
}
```

However, the problem is that I don't want to use *indexOf*. Furthermore, I am trying to make the code ***recursive***.

So I tried writing this code:

```
public class Index
{
  public static int indexOf(String main, String check)
  {

    int n = check.length();
    int i = main.length();

    int h = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      if (main.charAt(j) == check.charAt(j)) h++;
    }
    return h - 1;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(indexOf("Barack", "B"));
  }
}
```

However, this one doesn't work at all how it is supposed to and it isn't even recursive.

Is there anyway, I can make this method recursive and not use indexOf?

Comment: As of now, this question is too broad for us to answer. It's like if I asked you: "I have this green tricycle that doesn't fly.. is there any way I can turn it into a red car that does fly?" The answer is, well, probably. But **how** you do that is entirely up to you, and I would guess is the whole point of the homework assignment. What **specific step** are you stuck on?

Comment: Have a look at the [recursive linear search section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search#Recursive_version) in wikipedia, it might help you get started.

Comment: @Frecklefoot One common reason to use recursion to solve clearly iterative assignments is to learn how to use recursion.

Comment: For learning it's good but if you try to use recursion to solve a codingbat or similar problem with it it'll likely fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before making a method recursive it is beneficial to think about your task in recursive terms. What does it mean for a sub-string to start at a specific index of a string? One way to explain it recursively is as follows:

> An **index of a sub-string** is
>
> - -1, if the string is shorter than the substring
> - 0, if your string begins with the sub-string, or
> - 1 +  **index of the sub-string**, when the first character of the string has been removed, and the return value is positive
> - -1 if **index of the sub-string** returned -1

Highlighted portion indicates the spot where recursion has been applied: in order to compute the index of a sub-string we must compute the index of a sub-string in a shorter string.

This description can be converted to a recursive method almost literally:

```
int indexOf(String str, String sub) {
    if (str.length() < sub.length()) return -1;
    if (str.startsWith(sub)) return 0;
    int res = indexOf(str.substring(1), sub);
    return res < 0 ? res : 1+res;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/yAtLqK)

Comment: Thank you very much man. Your code is so nice and concise. However, can you explain the last line please? Thank you. :)

Comment: It will return the number of recursion the function will have made.

Comment: @JohnSmith The last line is a conditional expression. It checks if the recursive invocation returned -1, in which case it also returns -1. Otherwise it returns 1+whatever the recursive invocation has returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.company;

public class Index {
    public static int indexOf(String main, String check)
    {
        if (main.startsWith(check)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (main.length() < check.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            int indexOf = indexOf(main.substring(1), check);
            return indexOf < 0 ? -1 : 1 + indexOf;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(indexOf("Barack Obama", "Obama"));
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right of course. I great example of why "special" return values are not a good design pattern. Because careless programmers like me forget to take them into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine too, if you also don't want to use startsWith(). Here a part of check String is matched with the main String if previous part is all matched.

```
public class Index {

    public static int indexOf(String main, String check) {

        int i = main.length();

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (main.charAt(j) == check.charAt(0)) {
                if (check.length() > 1) {
                    if (indexOf(main, check.substring(1)) == j + 1) {
                        return j;
                    }
                } else {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(indexOf("My name is XYZ", "ashfbs"));//returns -1;
        System.out.println(indexOf("My name is XYZ", "is"));//returns 8;
    }
}
```